# Link To Another Record In a FLAT Access Database

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a simple flat database with about 40 fields.
Each record has a unique ID.

There are a few pairs of records which have a tenuous connection
and I would to place a link/bookmark on each record so that I can
jump directly to the connected record.

Is this *record to record* linking possible within a simple
flat database structure?

Comment: what you're looking for is called "self join", just google it.

Comment: Thanks Máté - I read up and viewed some videos on Self Joins.

I now understand the concept, but I can't figure how I would create
a clickable link to another record.

Comment: Do you mean in a table / query / form?

Comment: I mean a form.
If I am on record #25, I want to go directly to record #52 (for example) by clicking on a link in record #25

Comment: I forgot to say - It is a "Single Form"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few aspects to this and many possible solutions.

It seems the main questions/goals you have are:

1. What should the schema (tables) look like to allow for a linking between two records in the same table?
2. How to jump from one record on a form (single-view) to the related record?

There are several ways to link the records together. The simplest is probably a field on the table that contains the ID of the same table. The downside is that it is possible for the data to be inconsistent: if record 1 links to record 2 must record 2 link to record 1 in return? Maybe. Maybe it doesn't matter to you.

Note: If you need to link more than just pairs of records (i.e. groups of more than two) then the simple self-reference field won't work (unless you chain them, but - yuck). In this case you have to have another table which has records for each element in each group. I'll ignore this since you specifically said pairs of records.

So add a field to the table called something like `RelatedItemID`. It should be a number of the same data type as the ID of the table.

Next you want a way of creating the links. I suggest a combo-box on the form which lists all records from this table, and has a `ControlSource` set to the `RelatedItemID` field.

Finally, to jump to the related record is a simple matter of using VBA code behind a button.

```
Private Sub JumpToRelated_Click()
    Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "ID = " & RelatedItemID
    If Not Me.RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
        Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
    End If
End Sub
```

This will navigate the form to the related record.

To ensure consistency - i.e. enforcing the two way relationship - you might want some code in the AfterUpdate event of the combo-box to set the 'other' record's link to the current record, and clear the old link (if any). This is not mandatory - it just means the user would have to manually maintain the two-way relationship otherwise.

Comment: I'll give that a try andrew - Thank You. I am using [cID] as my primary key and [RELATED_1] as a bound field. I tried variation of this ...Private Sub CommandFF_Click()
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord , , , "[cID] = [RELATED_1]"
End Sub

Comment: Your code works really well andrew- Thank You. Unfortunately the system will not allow me to give you a Plus on your reply.